# Algebraically why is that $\cos(0) =1$?

Tags: trigonometry

I have been thinking about this for a day now but it seems every way is predicated on using either $\cos(0)=1$ and $\sin(0)=0$ as a giving to justify the argument. Is it possible to show this to be true without prior knowledge of sine and cosine at zero?

For example, if we use the identity $\cos^2(0) + \sin^2(0) = 1$, we have to assume knowledge of either $\cos(0)$ or $\sin(0)$, maybe I missed something. Then I thought about using the Taylor series at $x=0$ but not assuming it to be giving. By doing so, I end up with
\begin{align}
\cos(x) &= \cos(0) - x\sin(0) - \frac{x^2}{2!}\cos(0) + \frac{x^3}{3!}\sin(0) + \cdots\\
&= \cos(0)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!} - \sin(0)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\tag{1}\\
\cos(0) &= \cos(0)\cdot 1 - \sin(0)\cdot 0\\
\cos(0) &= \cos(0)
\end{align}
Therefore, I haven't reached $\cos(0) = 1$ unless I use it as a giving. Then I thought about the exponential $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$. Now this would work 
$$
e^{i\cdot 0} = \cos(0) + i\sin(0) = 1 + 0\cdot i
$$
so the imaginary part has to be zero, but if we derive the power series and not take Euler's formula for granted, we get
\begin{align}
e^{ix} &= \cos(0)\biggl[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}+i\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\biggr]\\ 
&+ \sin(0)\biggl[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\biggr]\\
e^0 &= \cos(0)[1+0\cdot i]+\sin(0)[1-0]\\
1 &= \cos(0) + \sin(0)
\end{align}
Now, I need to use $\sin(0)=0$ as a giving but the point is to not take these identities for granted.

For why I accept the derivative of $\cos$ to be $\sin$, the power series would be
$$
\sin(x) = \sin(0)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}+\cos(0)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\tag{2}
$$
Then derivative of $(2)$ is $(1)$ after a change of variables.

Comment: Suppose all we know about $\cos \theta$ is its definition in terms of angles of triangles. Then we can see that at $\theta = 0$ the adjacent and hypotenuse lie on top of each other, and their ratio is one.

Comment: @SirElderberry I want to show this algebraically not relying on geometry.

Comment: It's a definition. You can define cosine as the solution to $y''=-y$ satisfying $y(0)=1$.

Comment: How do you defined "algebraically" the cosine and the sine ?

Comment: @N.H. I used the power series.

Comment: Whats wrong with plugging $x=0$ into $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$?

Comment: @Mesih by assuming that form you are assuming $\cos(0) = 1$.

Comment: I think it would help if you told us what axioms you would feel comfortable using. You have to start with a definition of cosine somehow, otherwise you can't prove anything about it because it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: If you accept that the angle difference formula $$\cos(x-y) = \cos x \cos y + \sin x \sin y$$ has been established via the power series, then simply compute $\cos 0$ as $\cos(x-x)$ for any non-zero $x$ you happen to know the sine and cosine values for.

Comment: @symplectomorphic if we are going to define it as correct, it would be the same as just saying $\cos(0) =1$ by definition.

Comment: @dustin Then whats your definition of cosine?

Comment: Then you only assume sine and cosine are analytical functions ? There are plenty such functions. You have to give more precise description.
I downvote the question because you don't give a concrete definition of "cosine" and "sine".

Comment: He gave the restriction that the square sum is 1. That should limit the functions somewhat.

Comment: @Mesih do you see how I constructed the Taylor series? That is the definition. It doesnt simplify down to $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$ unless we have knowledge of $\cos(0)$ and $\sin(0)$.

Comment: It's false : just take $\cos(x+\pi/3)$ and $\sin(x+ \pi/3)$ says. Then, we still have $f^2+g^2 = 1$ but $f(0) \neq 1 \neq g(0)$...

Comment: That Taylor series is not the definition. It's just the expanion of an arbitary (presumably analytic) function $f$ at $0$, with the coefficient $f^{(n)}(0)$ replaced by $\pm \cos(0)$ and $\pm \sin(0)$. In other words, you're taking $\cos x$ to be the function with $y'(x) = -\sin x$ and $y''(x) = -\cos x$...except that that definition is obviously circular. If you want to take $\cos x$ to be the function with $y''(x) = -y(x)$, then it's still not going to be uniquely determined unless you set boundary conditions, such as specifying $y(0) = \cos 0$ and $y'(0) = \sin 0$.

Comment: And more simply, you can define $\cos$ in terms of $\exp$, which can be conviently defined as the unique function with $y' = y$ and $y(0) = 1$. Omit the latter condition, and you run into the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you define $\cos$ by $\cos x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$,
then $\cos 0 = 0^0 = 1$ (all other terms are $0$). If you define $0^0$ differently, you are not actally talking about the $\cos$ function. If you define $\cos x = \Re(e^{ix})$, then you get the same.

If you want to define $\cos$ via the differential equation:

$$\cos''(x) = -\cos(x)$$
then you need an initial value. Again, if you don't take $\cos(0)=1$, then you are not talking about the $\cos$ function. The choice is $\cos(0)=1$ is canonical, the only other canonical choice is mapping $0$ to $0$, but this is what $\sin$ already does.

Also, if $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$, then $1 + i0 = 1 = e^0 = e^{i0} = \cos(0) + i\sin(0)$, so by taking the real value: $\cos(0) = 1$.

Comment: Start with a function called $\cos(x)$. We don't know its definition so we say hey let's determine the taylor series. We get $f(0) = \cos(0)$, $f'(0) = -\sin(0)$ and so on. The power series then has cosine and sine involved. Unless we know something about the values at zero, the Taylor series doesn't lose the values.

Comment: @dustin How?  In what way do you get the taylor series?  Derivatives?  Then where did the definition of the derivative of cosine come from?  https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Sine_Function Each proof somehow relies on the value of at least one of cos(0) or sin(0), knowledge of the other's derivative, or from a richer definition of cosine than you are using.

Comment: @JMoravitz see edit. No knowledge is assumed to determine they are derivatives.

Comment: I also stated not to take Euler's formula for granted.

Comment: @dustin in which case as I understand, you take for definition of $\cos(x)$ that $\cos'(x) = -\sin(x)$ and $\sin'(x)=cos(x)$, and that $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$ from which it follows the series expansion.  By that definition you are in the central case of Stefan's answer, that your definition of $\cos$ is consistent with $y'' = -y$ to which there are multiple solutions.

Comment: @dustin As others pointed out already: Your reasoning is circular. You have to properly define $\cos$ somehow at some point (and I wouldn't recommend the definition via unit circle), it is not simply "there" by default. I know from school (at least in my school time), that often theorems and definitions were not really "separated", but this is bad practice and should be avoided.

Comment: @StefanPerko circular implies falling back on what you want to prove. I have never done so. I really think circular needs to be taught here. I don't fall back on $\cos(0)=1$ or sine is zero once.

Comment: @dustin Tell me: What IS $\cos$? ;)

Comment: @StefanPerko an operator name without an argument. I guess we could call that undefined since it makes no sense otherwise.

Comment: @dustin Let me rephrase this in simpler terms: What IS $\cos(x)$?

Comment: Suppose all we know $\cos(x)$ is some function. We can write the power series of it by Taylor's formula and come up with an polynomial of infinite order. This no way defines $\cos(0)$ since we don't know it yet. We then arrive at series representation that includes both a sine zero and cosine zero. I am not assigning them o and 1 respectively. If I did, that would be circular.

Comment: @dustin You are mistaken. If you don't "know" $\cos(x)$, then how are you going to reason about it, derive it's taylor series for instance? Let me define the term "bleeeerg". No, I won't tell you what "bleeeerg" means, but as you can "obviously" see, "bleeeerg" is green, wears pants and likes eating candy. Doesn't make sense? Of course not! Now replace "bleeeerg" by $\cos(x)$ and "is green, wears pants and likes eating candy" by "has taylor expansion ..." and we are back to our initial situation.

Comment: "suppose all we know is $\cos(x)$ is some function.  We can write power series of it by Taylor's formula."  That is true that we can write it in terms of its derivatives, but if all we know is that it is *some* function, we don't know what its derivatives *are*.  So, all we know is that $f(x)=\sum f^{(n)}(0)\frac{x^n}{n!}$.  Unless you define $cos(x)$ further beyond just "some function" such as defining $cos'(x)=-sin(x)$ and $cos''(x)=-cos(x)$ in which case you are at the solutions of $y'' = -y$ which has multiple solutions.  Only once you add more to the definition are you able to know cos(0)

Answer (score 2):

For me, cosine was defined analytically using the infinite sum $$\cos(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\ldots$$

from which you can see that $\cos(0)=1$

Which definition do you want to use?

Comment: Derive that definition without assuming $\cos(0)=1$ and you have a bunch of $\cos(0)$ hanging around.

Comment: It's a definition, and therefore cannot be derived. We can define $\cos$ in this way, in which case it is apparent that $\cos(0) =1$, or we can define $\cos$ in terms of triangles, in which case it is also apparent that $\cos(0) = 1$.

Comment: What do you mean 'derive that definition'? This is my definition.

Comment: This agrees with the analysis definition of the cosine used here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Cosine

Answer (score 1):

you know that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{sinx}{x}=1$ geometrically. from here you know that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\sin x=0$. if you assume that the sine function is continuous, then you have that $sin(0)=0$, and from here it follows from $\sin^2(0)+\cos^2(0)=1$ that $cos(0)=\pm 1$. if you also assume that the cosine function is continuous, then $cos(0)$ couldn't be negative, because $\cos x\geq 0$ for $0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, which is defined geometrically.

so if $\cos(0)$ can't be negative, we've established that $\cos(0)=1$

Comment: cos0=0?????????

Comment: here, happy? ;)

Comment: You have write @name otherwise adg won't know you said anything.

Answer (score 0):

If we define cos and sin on the unit circle as x and y coordinates on the periphery.. then at length 0 along the circle ("angle" 0) we will be at coordinate (1,0) so cos will be 1 and sin will be 0.

Comment: I want to show this algebraically not relying on geometry.

Comment: Ok so you are fine with trigonometrical one i.e. sum of squares is 1. Then the taylor expansion of sin(0) will be 0 so cos(0) must be either -1 or 1 according to that sum of squares = 1.

Comment: this is in no way wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Anything you do would be useless, since all this is defined once and everything is based upon it. Even Euler's Formula and Taylor series  use the definition that $\cos0=1,\sin0=0$. The following could be taken as a starting point while neglecting any geometrical consequence:
$$y''=-y$$
And the solution will be of the form of:
$$a\sin x+b\cos x$$
(where a,b are **variable constants**)

Suppose someone unknown about trigonometric functions wanted to define them, he would take two starting functions:
$$\sin_2x=c\sin x+d\cos x\\\cos_2x=e\sin x+f\cos x$$
(where c,d,e and f are **constants**)

And then to him the solution of above equation would be:
$$a_2\sin_2x+b_2\cos_2x$$

Now if did took $(c,d,e,f)\equiv(1,2,3,4)$, then $\sin_20$ would be $2$ and $\cos_20=4$.

Now the special solution we use is $(1,0,0,1)$ , because it follows a nice property:
$$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$$
but his does:
$$(\cos_2x-2\sin_2x)^2+\left(\frac{3\sin_2x-\cos_2x}2\right)^2=1$$
There are also other unmentioned advanted, one involving range too, since $|\sin x|,|\cos x|<1$ but $|\sin_2x|<\sqrt{5},|\cos_2x|<5$. There is surely an advantage with that solution if considering without any geometrical basis. When geometry comes into play, there's no choice left...

Comment: Prior to having the knowledge we have today, mathematicians had to find a way to prove it to be true without saying I know this to be true. How was it done in this case, because unless I know something useful about $\cos(0)$ or $\sin(0)$, making the conclusion $\cos(0)=1$ doesn't seem to come so naturally. Once $\cos(0)=1$ is known the other will follow.

Comment: @dustin that follows from geometrical ease. Also you could have $\cos_2x=\sin x$ an $\sin_2x=\cos x$then $\cos_2(0)=0$ and all formulas are interchanged, **it's just an easy definition** which when defined like this become the functions related to triangles.

Comment: I found a solution from ancient Greece.